# Is every file in Python considered a module?

Tags: python

What exactly is a Python module? From what I've read, it seems like **any** Python file can be considered a module.

With that in mind, is it true that python modules are needed if object orientation is to be used in a python program?

Comment: Yes, the two are synonymous.

Comment: By _object orientation_ do you mean _one class per file_? Because those are not synonymous.

Comment: I think your professor is getting at the fact that you can have multiple classes and such in one module.

Comment: @keyser So do you think the statement would be false or true? Because a single module can have a class in it, and we can create instances of that without having that class be located in another module. Making his statement false, no?

Comment: Well, it depends on the interpretation of "modules". _A_ python module will be used, but multiple isn't necessary. Just make sure you understand what a module is and you can't go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but every program requires at least one module in order to run code, regardless of whether your code is object oriented or not, though it is typical to create different files for different purposes.